# Percentage URL encoding in C++

Tags: c++, http

I want to encode my URL using percentage encoding.Is there any API  available for this purpose?.Can anyone provide a possible solution for this percentage encoding.Is there any third party library is available for this purpose?

Comment: At last i found out an API for URL Encode/Decode--> UrlCanonicalize. This is a shell api, we can use this API for Encoding or Decoding our URL.
Please Refer below link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773768(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way might be to iterate over the string you want to encode, and for each character in the string output a `'%'` followed by the two-digit hexadecimal ASCII value of that character. If the string is in ASCII of course.

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard API to do that. You can use any 3rd-party library or code to do that.
[Here's a possible solution.](https://gist.github.com/aslatter/2579752)

Comment: ==> Thanks for your information.Let me know the third party libraries?

Answer (score 1):

It is not hard to make your own functions with some knowledge of maths, however
for the beginning you can take a look at [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) and its two functions in its [api](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/):

```
char *curl_easy_escape(CURL* curl, char* url, int length);
char *curl_easy_unescape(CURL* curl, char* url, int inlength, int* outlength);
```